# How can I insert mutiple items in a DynamoDB table and wait if it exceeds maximum capacity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a json file with about 700 items I need to insert in a DynamoDB table. I'm currently using transactWrite but it's taking too long to insert all those items. How can I use batchWrite and if exceeds 25 items then wait and run the function again until all items are inserted?

```
data.forEach(async item => {
    const params = {
      TransactItems: [
        {
          Put: {
            Item: {
              pk: `User_${id}`,
              sk: 'v0_User_Info',
              val: item.User,
              editTimeStamp: `${+new Date()}`,
              latest: 1,
            },
            TableName: 'ddb-table',
          },
        },
        {
          Put: {
            Item: {
              pk: `User_${id}`,
              sk: 'v1_User_Info',
              user: item.User,
              editTimeStamp: `${+new Date()}`,
            },
            TableName: 'ddb-table',
          },
        }, 
      ],
    };
     await docClient.transactWrite(params).promise()
     .then(response => console.log(response))
     .catch(err => console.table(err))
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[batchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property) returns a field called [UnprocessedItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#DDB-BatchWriteItem-response-UnprocessedItems) which contains which items couldn't be processed and should be retried.  If this list is empty, then everything was written successfully.  `UnprocessedItems` is the exact same format as the batch request so you should be able to directly pass it to a new batch request.

For some sample code on looping and retrying the `UnprocessedItems`, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757857/1806763) to a similar question.